# VueJS - Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I created a component, i'm trying to use in Dashboard page but it says

```
vue.esm.js?efeb:4493 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at Watcher.get (vue.esm.js?efeb:4502)
at new Watcher (vue.esm.js?efeb:4477)
at mountComponent (vue.esm.js?efeb:4082)
at VueComponent.Vue.$mount (vue.esm.js?efeb:9063)
at VueComponent.Vue.$mount (vue.esm.js?efeb:11974)
at init (vue.esm.js?efeb:3127)
at createComponent (vue.esm.js?efeb:5989)
at createElm (vue.esm.js?efeb:5936)
at VueComponent.patch [as __patch__] (vue.esm.js?efeb:6488)
at VueComponent.Vue._update (vue.esm.js?efeb:3954)
```

I tried other solutions, nothing worked yet. I am trying to change names, changing the import type but nothing worked yet. Any thoughts?

I tried to change names like, is there anything i need to add or do?

Sidebar.vue

```
    <template>
    <sidebar id="Sidebar">
        <nav>
            <h1>BB</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Anasayfa
                </li>
                <li>
                    Yönetim
                </li>
                <li>
                    Üye Oluştur                    
                </li>
                <li>
                    <details>
                        <summary>Mesajlar</summary>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Kullanıcı</li>
                            <li>Kullanıcı 2</li>
                            <li>Kullanıcı 3</li>
                        </ul>
                    </details>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </sidebar>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'Sidebar',
    data: function(){
        return{
            users: [],
            staff: null
        }
    }
}
</script>
<style scoped>
sidebar {
    width: 30%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #dbdbdb;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

sidebar nav {
    width: 90%;
    margin-top: 30vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

sidebar h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 48px;
    color: #3A3A3A;
}
</style>
```

Dashboard.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <Sidebar/>
        Dashboard
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import Sidebar from './reals/Sidebar'

export default {
    name: 'dashboard',
    components: {
        Sidebar
    }
}
</script>
```

I also tried to add component to other page, but still not works. If you want more information i can give

Comment: Looks like something is recursing until an error. Have you added any new environment variables, lately?

Comment: Yes, i added environment variables to .env file but i didn't use variables anywhere.

Comment: Your root element of your sidebar should be renamed. it refers to the component it self. So sidebar is loading sidebar. Use aside instead (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_aside.asp)

Comment: That looks right, yep, sidebar is loading sidebar, which contains sidebar, so load sidebar, which contains sidebar, so load sidebar, which contains sidebar....

Comment: Thanks to dreijntjens. Solved, thx a lot guys!